# jquery toggle class not working when is in other div

Tags: javascript, jquery

hi guys I am doing a toggle effect in my page, but i got error when i move the button close for other part of the page. If the button is in a part of html works if are for example in other div the button does not work.can you guy figure out what is going on? also can u say if that my jquery is clean? or need to be improved?

html:

```
<a href="#menu-toggle" class="btn btn-sidebar-close" id="close">
    <i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</a>

<a href="#menu-toggle" id="menu-toggle"data-toggle="tooltip>
    <i class="fa fa-search fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</a>
```

js:

```
$('#close').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#wrapper').toggleClass('toggled');
});

$('#menu-toggle').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#wrapper').toggleClass('toggled');
});
```

Comment: better if you make a fiddle, and replicate the situations, because the code above are not enough to show what is the real problem,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An improvement could be:

```
$('#close').click(function(e) {
       e.preventDefault();
       $('#wrapper').toggleClass('toggled');
});

$('#menu-toggle').click(function(e) {
       e.preventDefault();
       $('#wrapper').toggleClass('toggled');
});
```

in a single function as they're both containing the same functionality:

```
$('#close, #menu-toggle').click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $('#wrapper').toggleClass('toggled');
});
```

Comment: thanks for the help, its always good learn good standards for the code, thanks a lot.

Comment: @Raduken no worries man, generalisation is extremely important and it's good to grasp it early on.

Comment: I just not understand some guys here, just come to criticize somebody code, just because the person has no knowledge, I am not saying on that thread, but anyway thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to close quote after "tooltip" here :

```
<a href="#menu-toggle" id="menu-toggle"data-toggle="tooltip">
   <i class="fa fa-search fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</a>
```

Otherwise, your code is working :

[See this Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sokbpv0m/2/)